# Where can I find about the specify api about the components of kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I feel very confused when use the kubernetes!
Where can I find about the specify api about the components of kubernetes ? such as `pod`, `service`, `volumes`, and `Persistent Volumes` and so on, when I create the components use the configure files.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about this question, I had find it.

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions.html